# How to close a position only if it's positive

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to set a condition to close my position only if the trade is positive. Meaning that if the condition to close my trade happened but we are actually negative then it doesn't close the trade and wait for the moment this closing condition happen again when we are in the green ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the profit of the latest open trade. Combine it with your exit condition.

```
open_profit = strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1)

is_exit = my_exit_cond and (open_profit > 0)
```

Then use `is_exit` to exit a trade.